# Installing PySimulator

Tags: python, modelica, dymola

I tried to install PySimulator: https://github.com/PySimulator/PySimulator
After following the first step: "Start "Install PySimulator.bat". This batch file installs the 32 Bit Python(x,y) and all other necessary packages.", there isn't a "PySimulator-Icon" only a Python(x,y)-Icon.
1. Is this correct? I don't know how to use this.. 
2. How can I open the GUI "Simulation and Analysis Environment", like it is shown here: http://elib.dlr.de/81304/1/PySimulator-MODPROD.pdf
Thankful for any help!

When I'm trying to install it via conda like in https://modelica.org/events/modelica2017/documents/3ds_TestingTutorialSlides.pdf
 (slide 43)

It works until

```
python setup.py install
```

Then I get the following error:

```
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/distribute/distribute-0.6.34.tar.gz
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 5, in <module>
    distribute_setup.use_setuptools()
  File "C:\pysim\src\distribute_setup.py", line 154, in use_setuptools
    return _do_download(version, download_base, to_dir, download_delay)
  File "C:\pysim\src\distribute_setup.py", line 133, in _do_download
    to_dir, download_delay)
  File "C:\pysim\src\distribute_setup.py", line 203, in download_setuptools
    src = urlopen(url)
  File "C:\Users\annes\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\PySim\lib\urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\annes\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\PySim\lib\urllib2.py", line 435, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Users\annes\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\PySim\lib\urllib2.py", line 548, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Users\annes\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\PySim\lib\urllib2.py", line 473, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Users\annes\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\PySim\lib\urllib2.py", line 407, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\annes\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\PySim\lib\urllib2.py", line 556, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: SSL is required
```

Answer (score 1):

If the installation was succuessful and only the icon is missing you should be able to start PySimulator from the command line with

```
python.exe -m PySimulator
```

Comment: Trying this I get the following error: C:\Python27>python.exe -m PySimulator
C:\Python27\python.exe: No module named PySimulator

Comment: I also had no luck with the bat installer. You could try the manual installation with anaconda as described in https://modelica.org/events/modelica2017/documents/3ds_TestingTutorialSlides.pdf on slide 43

Answer (score 0):

Did you see the [Wiki](https://github.com/PySimulator/PySimulator/wiki/Installation)? It links mostly to C. Gohlke's repository. If any dependency is missing by now, let me know, I have them archived locally.